# Why is my GitHub Actions workflow not producing any artifacts?

Tags: git, github-actions

My project in GitHub Actions is going fine, but there is no output (artifact). The essence of all manipulations is as follows - I use the Docker file as a container, I deploy the debian distribution with the iproute2 utility in github actions. The /bin/ss -tulpn command is executed in the container, which receives a list of open ports - the result is written to a file. The file is uploaded to a directory mounted to the container and used as an assembly artifact (packed in tar or deb). Output: workflow file, Dockerfile, successfully completed actions process, artifact, in one of the formats.

build.yml

```yaml
name: Build and Package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker container
      run: |
        docker build -t mycontainer .
        docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output mycontainer
        
    - name: Change permissions
      run: |
        sudo chmod -R 777 output/
        
    - name: Create artifact
      run: |
        cd output
        tar -cvzf result.tar.gz result.txt
        mv result.txt result.deb
      if: always()

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: result-artifact
        path: output/result.tar.gz
```

docker.yml

```yaml
name: Example Workflow

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build and run Docker container
      run: |
        docker build -t mycontainer .
        docker run -v $(pwd)/output:/output mycontainer
```

docker file

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iproute2

RUN mkdir /output

CMD /bin/ss -tulpn > /output/result.txt
```

I tried to look for a solution on the Internet, but, alas, I came to a stupor, because I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: `CMD` command inside your docker file is run during the build process, not during the container startup. You should use `ENTRYPOINT` or `RUN` command to give a custom entrypoint to your docker image.

Comment: @Dogacel Can you please tell me what it should look like? I sit all day - my head is in a mess :( 

RUN /bin/ss -tulpn > /output/result.txt , right?

Comment: Oops my bad, `CMD` command should run immediately after the docker image build process. That looks right.

One thing to note, can you do some basic operation like `echo "123" >> /output.txt` to make sure that file is not empty? Add echo to lines. A screenshot from your job run can also help.

Comment: @Dogacel Oh, so it was necessary to do these commands in Linux?) I just immediately started testing in github actions, here is the repository link https://github.com/HECCYLLIujTbmy/popytka-realizovat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and an artifact was created. Did you try to create something like this? [image]

It's a misunderstanding maybe. The repository is at the link https://github.com/montao/glowing-computing-machine/actions/runs/5407377909 if it helps.

Comment: https://github.com/HECCYLLIujTbmy/originaly-code-from-sof/actions/runs/5409203599 
it's strange, either I didn't understand something, or something is missing from me. I tested the code, but I don't see the artifact at the bottom:(

Comment: I figured it out, thank you all, especially you)

Answer (score 1):

In short, the code was working, but because of the strange github interface, the artifact was difficult to find. In fact, it was located along the following path Actions / Build and package.